# factorial function input int, output real?

Tags: sml, smlnj

This is absolutely driving me nuts.  The supposed simplest thing I can imagine and I can't do it.

I just want to computer factorial inputting an int and output a real.

I've tried to coerce in numerous way.

```
fun factorial 0 = 1 |
    factorial n = n * factorial(n-1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert an int to a real, you use `Real.fromInt`. If you want to return reals, you should also return `1.0` instead of `1` as the base case. So your code becomes:

```
fun factorial 0 = 1.0
  | factorial n = (Real.fromInt n) * factorial(n-1);
```

Comment: YOU ARE THE FREAKIN MAN!!!!!!  I kept attempting n:real or real(n) while also using 1.0.  now my factorial helper functions works properly for the rest of my functions...

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, n! = (n-1)! * n .  Unless i'm misunderstanding things (which is possible; i don't know ML), your function will always return 1 because it's never multiplying by n.

```
fun factorial 0 = 1 |
    factorial n = n * factorial(n-1);
```

I don't know how you return a real rather than an int, or whether this code even does it, but at the very least it should give you a correct value.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning the trailing semi-colon is superfluous.

Comment: was just a mistype on my part.. I have it coded correctly at least int -> int, you need to know ML to coerce properly to a real.

Comment: I use the ; just out of habit..  I know it's unneeded but I do it just for visual organization.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.standardml.org/Basis/real.html#SIG:REAL.fromInt:VAL